# Use same hotkey to toggle between distinct input functions?

Tags: shortcut

How can we set *one single hotkey* to cycle-toggle between *a number of input functions*?

It should work pretty much like the 'Tab' hotkey, for instance, which toggles between 'Object' and 'Edit' modes.

Comment: There is no single universal operator for that, depends on what you want to do under which context. Could be `object.mode_set` or `wm.context_toggle` or `wm.context_menu_enum` or any other number of operators. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For instance, I would prefer to use a single key to toggle between commands like "Mesh select mode" (vertex, edge and face).

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. You can use `wm.context_set_value` with context set to `tool_settings.mesh_select_mode` to change between two modes, but I don't think you can toggle between several of them without some more advanced python scripting